# Clustering of Sparse Time Series

Tags: time-series, clustering

I have a dataset of certain user activity per week (e.g. purchasing an item or using a service per week) for the past 52 weeks and for 100K+ users. The matrix is very sparse (85% of the entries are zeros). so, it looks something like this:

```
          W52  W51 .... W01
User01     0    1        0
User02     0    0        0    
...
User99     0    0        2
...
```

`W01` is the most recent week.

My question is whether there are good techniques to cluster the users based on their corresponding time series.

Comment: Not sure if this Dynamic Time Warping together with Time Series Distances would help, but there is a relatively new package  in python you can try: https://github.com/wannesm/dtaidistance, and this one a rather older example of Dynamic Time Warping together with KNN: https://github.com/markdregan/K-Nearest-Neighbors-with-Dynamic-Time-Warping

Comment: I think your data is too coarse for any meaningful results. How do you intend to verify the patterns you find?